# Division of 2 different Infinite Nested square roots

Tags: nested-radicals, infinitesimals

Has anyone come across the following type of nested square roots problem?[image: Calculator image]

$\sqrt{2-{\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{2+...n times {\sqrt{2}}}}}}}$ **divided by**

$\sqrt{2-{\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{2+...(n+1)times {\sqrt{3}}}}}}}$

Converging towards 3 as the 'n' increases

Are there any theorem or formulas to calculate multiplication or division of infinite nested square roots?

*Note*: 2nd sum done in calculator has same $\sqrt3$ at its end which is not visible. Just one term of nested square root is increased which is shown in picture

$\sqrt{2}$ = $2cos(\frac{\pi}{4})$

$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ = $2cos(\frac{\pi}{8})$

$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$ = $2cos(\frac{\pi}{16})$
.
.
.

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}$ = $2sin(\frac{\pi}{32})$ or $2sin(\frac{\pi}{2^5})$

$\sqrt{3}$ = $2cos(\frac{\pi}{6})$

$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ = $2cos(\frac{\pi}{12})$

$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}$ = $2cos(\frac{\pi}{24})$

$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}$ = $2cos(\frac{\pi}{48})$

.
.
.

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}}$ = $2sin(\frac{\pi}{96})$ = $2sin(\frac{\pi}{3*2^5})$

This looks more interesting to note

$\frac{2sin(\frac{\pi}{2^5})}{2sin(\frac{\pi}{3*2^5})}$

For very small values. "x" and "sin(x)" are almost the same
(as long as "x" is in Radians!)

It is true that $\frac{(\frac{\pi}{2^5})}{{(\frac{\pi}{3*2^5})}}$ simplifying to 3?

Is there any other means like, using limits or integration to solve such problems?

Please throw light me someone

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, you seem to have basically proven it. We want to show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{3\cdot 2^n}} = 3
$$
We would like to use that $\sin x \approx x$ for small $x$. To be rigorous, we can write $\sin x = x + xo(1)$, where $o(1)$ is a function that goes to $0$ as $x\to0$. Then
$$
\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{3\cdot 2^n}}
= \frac{\frac{\pi}{2^n} + \frac{\pi}{2^n}o_1(1)}{\frac{\pi}{3\cdot 2^n} + \frac{\pi}{3\cdot 2^n}o_2(1)}
= \frac{3+3o_1(1)}{1+o_2(1)}
\underset{n\to\infty}\to 3
$$
Alternatively, we can use the well known fact that $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$ for $x\to0$. Thus:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{3\cdot 2^n}}
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{3\cdot 2^n}}
\cdot \frac{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}
\cdot\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{3\cdot 2^n}}{\frac{\pi}{3\cdot 2^n}} \right)
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}{\frac{\pi}{3\cdot 2^n}}
= \lim_{n\to\infty}3 = 3
$$

Comment: What is the proof of limit n tends to infinity $\frac{sin(\frac{a*\pi}{2^n})}{sin(\frac{\pi}{2^n})} = a$

Is there any formula or proof?

Comment: You can do exactly the same proof as either of the two in my answer. Just swap out all the fractions as appropriate.

Comment: Yes. That is also my question. But please observe that division - an inverse of multiplication brought number 3 to numerator. To put the question in simple words whether sin (ax/2^n) divided by sin (x/2^n) = a I'm asking only for $limit _ n tends to infinity$

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion. But as I said, you can just do the proof as before. You get $\approx \frac{\frac{a\pi}{2^n}}{\frac{\pi}{2^n}} = a$. To do the formal limit arguments, you need to copy the proof.

Comment: Yeah done 
Thank you so much

Comment: However, what we have essentially proved is that $\frac{\sin(ax)}{\sin(x)} \to a$ as $x\to 0$. That covers all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post this as a comment, but my MathJax just isn't good enough to get in right in the comment box, without being able to see the rendered output.

It looks like a triviality to prove the formulas you are hinting at for the finite nested radicals.

As for 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\sin\frac{\pi}{2^5}}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{3\cdot2^5}}=3,$$
that's an immediate consequence of $\lim_{x\to0}{\sin x\over x}=1$